# unable to compile this PHP Code, can't find the error

Tags: php, class

I am new to the OOP Concepts of PHP. I can't find what is wrong with this program. Please help.

```
    <?php 

    class tell()
    {
    public var $message="Hi";

        function tellmessage()

        {


        $m=$this->message;
        return $m;

        }
    };

    $a = new tell();
    echo $a->tellmessage();

    ?>
```

Comment: few things here I need to know. why are you using `var` here? what exactly you need to do here?

Comment: FYI: PHP is not a compiled programming language

Answer (score 2):

First, after the class name, `()` are not needed, that will give a syntax error.

And second, based on your php version, the `var` reserved word is deprecated or not.

For newer versions, var and `public` are synonimous, so you should use either but not both at the same time.

so either you use:

```
public $message="Hi";
```

or:

```
var $message="Hi";
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Note class are blueprint of object so use {}

```
  <?php 
      class tell
        {
          public $message="Hi";
          function tellmessage()
          {
            $m=$this->message;
            return $m;
          }
      };
    $a = new tell();
    echo $a->tellmessage();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
Class tell
{
    Public $message;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->message='Hi';
    }

    function tellmessage()
    {
        $m=$this->message;
        return $m;
    }
}

$a = new tell();
echo $a->tellmessage();
die;
```